# Glassfish Error when deploying WAR - Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource :

Tags: java, deployment, web, glassfish, war

I'm trying to deploy a WAR file called "VodfoneContractsDB.war". Its a simple web service created using Netbean's "RESTful Web Service from Database" wizard.

"Vodafone" is the name of my database connection.

I get the following error message:

> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app :
>   Invalid resource : Vodafone__pm. Please see server.log for more
>   details.

This is the log file:

```
[#|2012-10-01T09:23:35.542+0400|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.Request|_ThreadID=119;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC4011: Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called|#]

[#|2012-10-01T09:23:36.052+0400|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=119;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GUI deployment: uploadToTempfile|#]

[#|2012-10-01T09:23:36.052+0400|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=119;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|======= uploadFileName=VodfoneContractsDB.war|#]

[#|2012-10-01T09:23:36.567+0400|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=121;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method|#]

[#|2012-10-01T09:23:36.567+0400|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=121;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while preparing the app|#]

[#|2012-10-01T09:23:36.568+0400|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=121;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Invalid resource : Vodafone__pm
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : Vodafone__pm
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:540)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:469)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupPMResource(PersistenceHelper.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:120)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:495)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:233)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1066)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:207)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:148)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : Vodafone__pm
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl$MyDataSource.validateResource(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl$MyDataSource.setResourceInfo(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:255)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:245)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:538)
    ... 63 more
|#]

[#|2012-10-01T09:23:36.635+0400|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=121;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : Vodafone__pm
com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : Vodafone__pm
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl$MyDataSource.validateResource(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl$MyDataSource.setResourceInfo(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:255)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:245)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:538)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:469)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupPMResource(PersistenceHelper.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:120)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:495)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:233)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1066)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:207)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:148)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
|#]

[#|2012-10-01T09:23:36.641+0400|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=119;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception Occurred :Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : Vodafone__pm. Please see server.log for more details.|#]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is making the resource an application-wide resource. Make sure you make the JNDI name prefixed with java:app/. And so, in your case, it'll be java:app/Vodafone. This should be done in both your persistence.xml file and in the WEB-INF/glassfish-resources.xml file also.
Find more details at [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/pongegf-1517943.html)

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to http:/localhost:4848
2. click on JDBC in the left navigation tree and expand it, choose JDBC Connection Pool
3. create your Connection Pool
4. create an JNDI name for your connection pool
5. retry to deploy your application.

Good luck
Patrick

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue. I put a jdbc/ in front of the jta-data-source value in the persistence.xml and it resolved the issue. Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this suggestion.
http://blog.pinateknoloji.com/glassfishapplication-scoped-resources

It works for me. You need to define your datasource in glassfish-resources.xml and put this file in your WEB-INF.
Remember to prepend your datasource with java:app/ so it reads java:app/Vodafone.
and use this value in your persistence.xml java:app/Vodafone

Answer (score 0):

This is my fault cases met.
Here, I make the steps to create JNDI glassfish handmade crafts for MySQL connections.
You do the same with your database.
Based on glassfish-resources.xml file in NetBean do you configure JNDI property to suit accordingly

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-glassfish-config.html

Comment: hmm .. answer or follow-up question? bit hard to understand - at least for me :-)